# How did Crichton know where to find Jool in S4E2 (What Was Lost)?

Tags: farscape

At the end of season 3, Moya is sucked into a wormhole, leaving Crichton stranded.

In the very second episode of season 4, Crichton heads towards a planet to find Jool.  I didn't notice any explanation of how he knew where she was: he mentions having talked to her, but how did they get in contact in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

In the very first episode of season 4, Crichton is rejoined by Chiana and Rygel, who were both on board Moya (with Jool) when it was sucked into the wormhole at the end of season 3.

It is, therefore, most likely that they knew where Jool was.

Comment: Yes, that is what I had understood from watching the series.  Jool was on Moya with Chiana and Rygel at the end of season three as well.